# How to download excel and doc file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using this code, but I can't download `excel` and `doc` files.

```
public function download_document($fileName=null){
    if ($fileName) {
        $file = realpath ( "uploads/user_img" ) . "\\" . $fileName;
        // check file exists    
        if (file_exists ( $file )) {
            // get file content
            $data = file_get_contents ( $file );
            //force download
            force_download ( $fileName, $data );
        } else {
            // Redirect to base url
            redirect ( base_url () );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure the file exists in uploads/user_img/some.docx ? The path name suggests you store images there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:-

```
public function download_document($fileName=null){
    $this->load->helper('download');
    if ($fileName) {
        $file = "uploads/user_img/" . $fileName;
        // check file exists    
        if (file_exists ( $file )) {

            //force download
            force_download ( $file, NULL );
        } else {
            // Redirect to base url
            redirect ( base_url () );
        }
    }
}
```

Please follow below link.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html